# Принцип работы i2p. Есть вопрос.

Tags: p2p

Поставил приложения и возник вопрос "как?"
Читаю википедию и форумы и вижу:

```
ваш личный идентификатор в сеть не посылается, таким образом произвести аналогию IP и I2P ID — невозможно.
```

Хорошо. Тогда, например, когда я поднял сайт в сети и кто-то хочет на него зайти и у него нет ip сайта. Чтобы послать пакет нужен ip куда послать (не будем вникать в цепочку узлов). Получается, он должен отправить запрос на "общий" сервер или не знаю.
Читаю дальше.

```
NetDB хранятся и ключи, сообщающие о подлинности информации опубликованной там.
Что еще там хранится?
— Статистика установки тунелей у нод 
— Количество успешно установленных соединений через ноду
— Количество отброшенных соединений
— Время таймаута при обращении к ноде
— Версия роутера (клиента I2P)
```

Нет ip поля адреса. Как так? Объясните нормальный языком. Спасибо.

Comment: Да, хороший вопрос. У меня тоже (уже сколько лет :( ) не доходят руки разобраться.

К сожалению, ответ @eicto ничего конкретного не добавил.

--

Пожалуй, для уточнения ситуации сначала хорошо бы получить ответ на чисто программистский вопрос:

     сокет какого типа (см. man 7 socket, man 2 soket, SEE ALSO...) надо создавать для обмена в p2p?

или

     есть ли примерчики (а лучше tutorial) на несколько сотен строк на Си в Linux клиента (инициатор запроса) и сервера (отвечающая часть)
     
Видимо от ответов зависит, какими будут следующие вопросы.

Comment: @avp, дополнил вопрос комментарием к @eicto.

Comment: > сокет какого типа (см. man 7 socket, man 2 soket, SEE ALSO...) надо создавать для обмена в p2p?

и второй вопрос тоже, 

реализация там видимо очень замороченная, так просто на C не переписать, ибо они уже не первый год хотят сделать C или C++ роутер, 

а общаться с p2p сетью можно обычным способом - используя любой клиент прокси (он коннектится через еще одну прослойку к роутеру и тот волшебным образом превращает ваш запрос из dns адреса в хэш p2p и сам там соединяется).

Comment: @eicto, а на чем кроме Си эта штука может быть написана? 

По крайней мере нижний уровень-то libc (никто ведь напрямую системные вызовы не кодирует). Вот и интересно, что именно из libc в каком случае они вызывают.

--

Вот представим ситуацию. Дома есть IP роутер (D-link), подключенный к провайдеру по ethernet. Дальше у провайдера, очевидно, NAT. Через другой ethernet порт к роутеру подключен комп (допустим, других интерфейсов у него нет). 

***Этот комп сможет общаться по p2p (i2p) с другими компами?***

Если да, то какие IP-заголовки д.б. у  пакетов, отсылаемых на домашний D-link?

Comment: @avp, @eicto задал сегодня еще один вопрос ( http://hashcode.ru/questions/334834/torrent-dht-%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE ), который поможет приоткрыть глаза на всю муть с поиском ip имея только хэш. Только представим, что искомый ip, это наш файл в сети, который хотим скачать.

Comment: @dal, статью в Вашем новом вопросе прочел. Там написано, что реально обмен идет по IP (UDP).

 Интересно, а есть альтернативные реализации, скажем, через WiFi с "соседями" по MAC? А уже где-то дальше gateway в IP.

--

Что Вам конкретно ответить, не знаю. Похоже, Вас интересует "внутренняя кухня" преобразований адресов p2p сети (хэшей) в IP, т.е. как устроен там, назовем эту штуку, "распределенный DNS".

Меня же больше интересует практический вопрос:

- каким образом мой домашний роутер может стать доступным для вызова в p2p сети извне (он ведь внутри 10-й сети у провайдера)?  Не знаете?

Comment: @avp так вы инициализируете соединение к соседям, где можно пробить nat через udp там пробивается (используя еще какой-нить сервер как координатор) или просто несколько установленных соединений. вот давайте попорще сеть возьмем - ethernet over ip, скажем подключили 500 разных узлов (те кто за nat подулючаютсяк тем у кого внешние адреса есть), ну и между собой кто может. не вижу ни одной проблемы существования такой сети, если хотя-бы у одного известного узла есть внешний адрес. Кроме того внешним адресом в i2p может быть ipv6 туннелированый вам от брокера.

Comment: @eicto, как только мы начинаем говорить о выделеных адресах (те же узлы, к которым я из под ната должен подключатьсь по vpn), так "моя пиринговость" сразу уменьшается. Т.е. как ретранслятор-роутер для сети я потерян (естественно,  в локалке могу все делать). Все взаимодействие опять становится клиент-сервер(а).

Или я не прав? (правда не знаю, как-то не разбирался пока в этой области).

--

А вот про тунелированный ipv6 поподробнее (но на пальцах) если можно (согласен, противоречивые требования).

Answer (score 2):

Ну как сказать, сети бывают **не только ip**, в i2p **ip сеть** - транспорт, а адресом служит специального вида **хэш**,  запросы к нему грубо говоря посылаются через ближайшего участника сети, который так-же посылает запрос своим соседям, и так, пока не найдется цепочка по которой будет установлено соединение, я не очень хорошо знаю архитектуру i2p, но скорее всего там используется что-то типа волнового алгоритма (посылаем всем, с какой стороны ответ пришел первым то направление и считается кратчайшей цепочкой), муравьи похожим образом еду ищут.

Answer (score 1):

в i2p ip сеть- транспорт. Хэш - адрес. Пусть есть база всех ip в сети (для транспорта). Волновым алгоритмом посылаются пакеты всем адресам, но так можно долго искать нужный сайт. Если цепочку узлов найдут, то не факт, что один с узлов прекратить существования + если сайт прекратить существования, то может зациклить. Поиск можно начать от ближайшего работающего узла. Также сама цепочка может быть очень длинной. Так можно связать хэш и ip (сверяя запрашиваемый хэш и свой), но загружать страничку будет долго, если учесть роста числа возможных пользователей, увеличения базы ip и неработающие узлы.